# Can I insert SDF data into an MDF?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have two databases:

1. `DatabaseA.mdf`
2. `DatabaseB.sdf`

Database B is a compact version of Database A. I would like to merge them together so I can eventually get rid of DatabaseB.

They have the same tables and same structure but how can I achieve this?

I want to write a C# program which will simply run something similar to the following script:

```
INSERT INTO [DatabaseA].[table] (column1, column2...) 
VALUES 
    (
    SELECT column1,column2... 
    FROM [DatabaseB].[table] 
    WHERE [UID] NOTIN [DatabaseA].[table]
    )
```

I am aware, this isn't the final query.

Many thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tones of ways, but I would use [DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx) in this case

1. Read from DB B into DataSet
2. Read from DB A into DataSet
3. Merge this two DataSets using [DataSet.Merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/803bh6bc(v=vs.110).aspx)
4. Store result DataSet into DB A

Comment: Thanks Arsen, I will look into this and ask questions if I have any. I didn't even think about this - seems obvious now.

Comment: The challenge here is to create correct data adapters, if you generate typed datasets, vs will do the task for you... so check typed datasets also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wha85tzb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Will do Arsen. My alternative was to convert it into XML and then import it. What do you reckon to that?

Comment: IMHO DataSet marge method do the most of the job, so with DataSets will be less code and faster to implement

Comment: Will this just allow data to be added at the bottom?

Comment: When you merge, all data that does not exists in B db will be added into DataSet, after which when you save dataset, this data will be inserted as new records... there is no add data to the bottom in DB, DB table is a set, so no guarantee where data goes